# How do you alphabetize based on dates, and put most recent at the top?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[Sample Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1wOIpR0YI8lt83ElY9kskO1NhAhAuN4uTKu2E97mMJl4/edit#gid=1662212506)

How do you reference the Data Import tab and display everything in order of most recent date at the top within the Worksheet, and alphabetize the Vendor Name (**column C - Worksheet**)?

I have tried the SORT function but little to no luck as it just alphabetized everything in order even when referencing the *Import Date* from the **Data Import**.

For visual reference

FIGURE 1:
[image]

FIGURE 2: Expected Outcome
[image]

**To further elaborate:**
This one might be tricky, but Column B will be hyperlinks and also needs to be in the correct order that also belongs to its proper data brethren. This is what I currently have and just references everything in order of new data incoming.

```
(=ARRAYFORMULA(IF('Data Import' !A:A<>"", HYPERLINK("Some_Website" & 'Data Import'!A4:A&, 'Data Import'!A3:A), ""))
```

This one I'm guessing will not only need to reference the date, but the naming order as well.

Comment: Have you tried using a query for this?

Comment: @ale13 No I have not tried query.  I did recieve some help recently. I'm currently exploring query and making some adjustments. I'm also seeing that there might already be an issue. There are sections of the worksheet that will have manual entry. Mean, that static entry will remain where it is, and the automated portions will keep pushing this static entry down.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. So this was resolved with the query function.

Source info: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en

The sample sheet will remain open to those who are in need of knowing how to use it and can view how it was used.

Doing this resulted in the expected outcome. However, there is an issue.

1. If you have other columns you intend to put manual data entry, this entry data will remain stagnant and will not move.
2. Only the columns with the query formula will be dynamic and will keep getting pushed downward while your stagnant entries will remain right where they are.

I'm currently looking into Assigned Index Numbers to resolved this.

[Solving the Dynamic / Static Data Alignment challenge using Alignment Index Numbers](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/95901649/solving-the-dynamic-static-data-alignment-challenge-using-alignment-index-numbers)